# Java Iterator for primitive types

Tags: java, iterator, primitive, private-members, autoboxing

I have a Java class of the following form:

```
class Example {

  private byte[][] data;

  public Example(int s) { data = new byte[s][s]; }

  public byte getter(int x, int y)         { return byte[x][y]; }
  public void setter(int x, int y, byte z) { byte[x][y] = z;    }
}
```

I would like to be able to externally iterate over the private data using an iterator like so:

`for(byte b : Example) { ;/* do stuff */ }`

I tried to implement a private Iterator class but I ran into problems:

```
private class ExampleIterator implements Iterator {
  private int curr_x;
  private int curr_y;

  public ExampleIterator() { curr_x=0; curr_y=-1; }
  public boolean hasNext() { 
    return curr_x != field.length-1
        && curr_y != field.length-1; //is not the last cell?
  }
  public byte next() { // <-- Error is here: 
                       // Wants to change return type to Object
                       // Won't compile!
    if(curr_y=field.length) { ++curr_x; curr_y=0; }
    return field[curr_x][curr_y];
  }
  public void remove() { ; } //does nothing
}
```

How would I implement an *external* iterator for primitive types (not generics)? Is this possible in Java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java 8 introduced [primitive iterators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PrimitiveIterator.html), that allow you to avoid boxing/unboxing during iteration over int, long and double collections.

You can create you own `PrimitiveIterator` of `byte` with typesafely implementing generic `PrimitiveIterator<Byte,ByteConsumer>`. `ByteConsumer` is also to be implemented. Both are pretty straightforward.

Why is there no `PrimitiveIterator.ofByte` in jdk? Probably because of machine word size, that is usually not smaller than int. Or byte iterators are better done by streams and such.

Comment: Is there an analogue `Iterable` for primitive types, so I can do `for(double d : myContainerWithDoubles) {}` ?

Comment: There is no for-each primitive iterator. Best match is to implement `PrimitiveIterator.OfDouble` and use it in functional fashion.

Answer (score 8):

An iterator cannot yield values of a primitive type. However, it could yield values of the wrapper type [`Byte`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html). Such values can be [auto-unboxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) into `byte` (as long as they are not `null`).

```
private class ExampleIterator implements Iterator<Byte> {
  public boolean hasNext() { ... }
  public Byte next() { ... }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
for (byte b : example) { ... }
```

Comment: I was unfamiliar with the concept of auto-(un)boxing. This is where my confusion stemmed from and where the solution was to be found.

Comment: Normally autoboxing like this is a way to generate a lot of garbage quickly. However, for `Byte`, I believe that most Java implementations use a flyweight pattern (since there are only 256 `byte` values), so there isn't an extra burden on the GC. Note, however, you'd have to use `for (byte b : instanceOfExample)` -- you can't iterate over a class.

Comment: @TedHopp Thank you for the technical insight, knowing what happens "behind the curtain" is always valuable!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use generics with primitives, as the generics require a class for the type.

What you can do is iterate over the Wrapper types (Integer, Byte, Boolean, etc)...

Answer (score 0):

Implement [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), and return a Byte object instead of a byte primitive:

```
class Example implements Iterable<Byte> {

..

    public Iterator<Byte> iterator() {
        return new MyIterator();
    }

    private class MyIterator implements Iterator<Byte> {
        public Byte next() {...}
        ....
    }
}
```

Implementing Iterable instead of Iterator allows you to loop on the object items directly, using the for-each loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your iterator to implement java.util.Iterator then next() will have to return Byte

```
class ByteArrayIterator implements Iterator<Byte> {
    final byte[] a; 
    int i = 0;
    ByteArrayIterator(byte[] a) {
        this.a = a; 
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return i < a.length;
    }

    public Byte next() {
        if (i == a.length) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        return a[i++];
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

remove can be implemented too. If you dont need it implemnent Iterator then we can change next() to return byte

```
    class ByteArrayIterator {
...
    public byte next() {
            if (i == a.length) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            return a[i++];
        }
```